# Debug Chrome Extensions with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know if it's possible to debug a Chrome Extension with Visual Studio Code? All the examples I've read involve a real web page with a url.

Comment: The github repo intro says all targets are listed on `http://localhost:<port>/json`. Judging by the issues page, it's possible but still buggy.

Comment: GabeMeister, have you found a way of doing this. I'm also looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 27):

For those who still finding the answer (like me, earlier), I have found the real solution and here's it is. This assumes that you have [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) already installed.

Instead of having native configuration support like Firefox does, you need to supply arguments to load the extension before running Chrome, specifically the `load-extension` argument.

Add this line inside your Chrome configuration object with the launch request, located on your `.vscode/launch.json` file. This assumes that your `manifest.json` file is directly on the workspace folder. If your `manifest.json` file is located in another folder, change the `${workspaceFolder}` accordingly.

```json
{
    "runtimeArgs": ["--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}"]
}
```

For example, this is how I do it on the `launch.json` file in my workspace.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "https://example.com/#this-could-be-anything",
            // Here it is!
            "runtimeArgs": ["--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}"]
        },
        { 
            // Firefox equivalent
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Firefox",
            "url": "https://example.com/#this-could-be-anything",
            "addonPath": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how to i add `brave browser` instead of `chrome`?

Comment: @alexzander This is about Chrome extension. I don't know if it is possible to do this with Brave, as it uses the Debugger for Chrome extension.

Comment: well, brave is built on `chromium`, so basically brave is chrome, but honestly i dont know too how to debug with brave, thats why i asked. maybe it would be possible if we modify the default browser path within vs code to `brave path`. i dont know if that is possible.

Comment: How do I add a custom path that has a space? e.g. Google has a space in "User Data" in their extension path. 

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\...

Comment: this may seem like a foolish question but what should i set under "url" property if i'm debugging a local chrome extension and debugging via localhost?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer you can put whatever URL you want. Put a specific website you want to try your extension on. For example `https://www.google.com`

Comment: Perfect. Took a while to find this but finally! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can debug extension code running on a web page using the `attach` option .

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Chrome Extension debugging",
    "port": 9222,
    "url": "<URL>",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/extension"
}
```

Remember to close any open instances of Chrome before starting Chrome in debug mode:

```
.\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

More information can be found here: [vscode-chrome-debug on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Yes, this answers the question I was able to debug it like that. Im adding additional information.

Comment: ... just make sure you have deployed the extension on your browser.

Comment: ... and reload it from the extensions cofiguration in chrome any time you need to debug new changes.

Comment: ... make sure you have deployed your extension in your chrome browser ... source deployed and source in vscode must be the same for debug breakpoints to match and fall in the right place

Comment: I'm assuming the extension is located at `${workspaceFolder}/extension`, so something like `${workspaceFolder}/extension/background.js` exists. If that's true, how do you load that into Chrome? Do you load the extension unpacked? Do you pass the same "${workspaceFolder}/extension" location in Chrome? 
I've tried this approach and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why does it say on the linked page that it doesn't support extensions? "Unsupported scenarios...-Debugging Chrome extensions"

Answer (score 4):

Yes it works, it is possible to debug the extension ...

Using [Debugger for Chrome extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) ..

First make sure you have all chrome windows closed ...
and configure an "Attach" debugging option like the following ...

```
  {
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "attach",
     "name": "Attach to Chrome",
     "port": 9222,
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src", <-- path to the root of the extension
     "url": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r" <-- Replace with the url (public or private) on which you want to debug your extension ...
      // IMPORTANT this url must exactly match the one in the address bar of the browser ..
  }
```

Then open chrome with the following command:

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

... then navigate to the url on which you want to debug your extension ...

... and finally, and only then ... Start your debugging session on vscode ...

Comment: This allows you debug "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r", not the extension you are testing. What if you wanna debug the "background page" of your extension?

Comment: Yes, It allows you to debug the extension, and you need to test the extension at some url, so that allows you to debug the extension at the url you set in the config according to the instructions ... I updated the description to make it more clear.

Comment: This works!!  Awesome!!  I was missing `webRoot`.  I thought it had something to do with VSCode hosting its own web server... but it's apparently nothing like that.  It just maps debug URLs to files.  Also, for anyone bundling... don't forget to embed sourcemaps with your extension during development.  You'll still use a `src` directory for `webRoot`.  Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this moment Google Chrome Extension can be debugged only using Chrome DevTool. 
... -> More Tools -> Extensions -> Your extension -> `Inspect views background page`

Regarding [vscode-chrome-debug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug):

**Supported features**

- Setting breakpoints, including in source files when source maps are enabled
- Stepping, including with the buttons on the Chrome page
- The Locals pane
- Debugging eval scripts, script tags, and scripts that are added dynamically
- Watches
- Console

**Unsupported scenarios**

- Debugging web workers
- Debugging Chrome extensions
- Any features that aren't script debugging